# How to check for null strings in a C array

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a C array declared like char* `arrayOfVarNames[3];`

This array is populated by some api and the strings in this array are again used by an objective-C method.

I want to know if there are any null strings in the arrayOfVarNames[3] before passing to the objective-C method. `NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithCString:arrayOfVarNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Anyway to check for null strings?

Comment: If you mean empty strings, then `strlen(the_char_ptr)==0`. If you mean null pointers, then `the_char_ptr==NULL`.

Comment: Easier still `!*the_char_ptr` resp. `!the_char_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `if` statement:

```
NSString *tempString = nil;
if (arrayOfVarNames[i]) {
    // It's not NULL
    tempString = [NSString stringWithCString:arrayOfVarNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
    tempString = @""; // or some other appropriate action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line code solution:

```
NSString *tempString = NULL == arrayOfVarNames[i] ? nil : [NSString stringWithCString:arrayOfVarNames[i] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with a *null string*, you test for:

- The pointer being `NULL`: `!p`
- The pointer pointing to an empty string: `!*p`

Beware that some interfaces handle those cases as interchangeable, so that you must accept both as an empty string.